# Is failure to call Continuation.resumeX() necessarily a problem?

Tags: kotlin, android-dialog, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using `suspendCoroutine` to avoid using callbacks in `Dialog`s. However, in Android `Dialog`s there is no obvious place to call `Continuation.resume()` when the dialog is dismissed (by clicking outside of the dialog area). If you attempt the call in `Dialog.setOnDismissListener()` then you have to keep track of whether resume was already called in the button listener.

```
suspend fun displayDialog() = suspendCoroutine<String?> { continuation ->
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    builder.setCancelable(true)
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel) { _, _ ->
        continuation.resume(null)
    }
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ ->
        continuation.resume("it's ok")
    }
    val dialog = builder.show()
    dialog.setOnDismissListener {
        // if the user clicked on OK, then resume has already been called
        // and we get an IllegalStateException
        continuation.resume(null)
    }
}
```

So, is it better to keep track of whether resume was already called (to avoid calling it a second time), or just don't bother with the `resume(null)` call (in onDismissListener)?

Answer (score 9):

Continuation is a low-level primitive that shall be resumed exactly once, so you have to track whether `resume` was already called when using it. Alternatively, you can use higher-level communication primitives, for example [`CompletableDeferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-deferred/), which has multi-use [`complete`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-deferred/complete.html) function:

```
suspend fun displayDialog(): String? {
    val deferred = CompletableDeferred<String?>()
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    builder.setCancelable(true)
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel) { _, _ ->
        deferred.complete(null)
    }
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ ->
        deferred.complete("it's ok")
    }
    val dialog = builder.show()
    dialog.setOnDismissListener {
        deferred.complete(null)
    }
    return deferred.await()
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks that's very useful. But I'm still curious what are the implications of not calling resume at all? For example, if the caller does not need to do any work when a dialog is dismissed and so potentially does not need to know this event. Are such paused coroutines using up resources?

Comment: A coroutine might potentially keep resources. For example, if a coroutine opens a file and calls `displayDialog` , then it will not close the file if the coroutines is not resumed. Moreover, coroutine debugging facilities keep a list of all coroutines, so if a coroutine is not resumed then it is stuck in that list forever -- memory leak.

Comment: Yes, regarding an open File, that's a case where the caller does need to do something (close the file), so I'm talking about the cost of being stuck in that list. Won't it be removed when the job is cancelled?